# XA or non-XA for JMS and DB operation

Tags: jms, websphere, rad, xa

I am fairly new to the XA and non-XA world. My requirement is to read a message from queue until there is a NO message. For each message in the queue, go to DB and do some transactions like select, insert, update.

Is this possible to achieve this using non-XA datasource? I am currently using XA datasource but learned that it is costly and performance hit.

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: you should probably explain how the queue is managed, what product is used. Some db vendors also offer queueing solutions, which will make your life easier.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to include in your transaction both interaction with a **JMS connection** (i.e. send or receive a message) and connecting with a database, by using a **db connection** then you definitely need an XA-datasource since your transaction is a **[two-phase commit (2PC) transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)**.

In a two-phase commit transaction you either commit the changes to all your resources (in your case JMS and DB resources) or rollback all changes if something goes wrong with either of them.

To do this you need to connect to an **XA-enabled datasource**. 
Additionally, in a Java EE container, **JMS Connections should already be XA-Enabled**.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [1.5 phase commit](http://blog.pasker.net/2010/10/21/use-jdbc-jms-without-jta/). Basically:

- step 1: You commit the DB transaction
- step 2: You commit the JMS transaction.

Possible error scenarios:

1. DB transaction fails.
2. DB transaction sucessful JMS transaction fails.
3. all successful.

Not 1, nor 3 leaves your system in inconsistent state. In case of 1, you just need to resend the message.

To handle scenario 2. you need to introduce duplicate check to your system. So essentially your transaction management would look like similar to this:

```
//pseudo code
if (isDublicate(message))
   commitJMSTransaction();
else
   doYourBusinessLogic();
   doYourDBOperation();
   commitDBTransaction();
   commitJMSTransaction();
```

If the JMS transaction fails your message broker will retry to send the message (or you need to resend it manually depending on your broker setup) but you duplicate check will detect it and remove it from the queue.

Answer (score 2):

To give you an idea of XA and NON-XA transations I explain it briefly,
An XA transaction is a "global transaction".
A non-XA transaction is a "local transaction".

An XA transaction involves a coordinating transaction manager, with one or more databases (or other resources, like JMS) all involved in a single global transaction. If it is connecting to multiple databases then it is XA.

Non-XA transactions have no transaction coordinator, and a single resource is doing all its transaction work itself. This will have only one database as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

XA guarantees that one message match 1 and only 1 DB transaction.
Let's think what happen without XA (just one of many possible situations):

1. The MDB pick a message
2. The MDB perform a DB job (let's say that every thing go well... no exceptions)
3. The application server jdk crash for some reason or there is a network failure while the MDB thread is still running
4. For simplicity let's consider that the server restart: since the MDB did not commit the transaction, for this reason the message is still on queue.
5. Another MDB get the message and repeat the DB transaction.

For our lucky, XA exist! :-)
From performances point of view there is a cost to pay, but always quality (of service) has a cost!

Comment: You are making several assumptions here, which are not necessarily correct: the database and the queueing system both must support the XA protocol.

Comment: These assumptions are in the question. He says that he can choose between XA datasource and non-XA but he's worried about performances. WebSphere Messaging does support XA, it's a requirement of J2EE specs. I showed just an example of how the XA helps.